# Regular Expression to replace a group

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace the space before the digits with some characters but i couldn't do that with the following regex:

```
    String parentString = " 1.skdhhfsdl 2. hkjkj 3.234hbn,m";
    String myregex = "/(\\s)[1-9]+./";
    String output = parentString.replaceAll(myregex, "$1ppp");
    System.out.println(output);
```

Please help me solve the regex.

**UPDATE**

After implementing the suggestion by @CertainPerformant and @Wiktor my code looks like,

```
String myregex = "(\\s)[1-9]+.";
String output = parentString.replaceAll(myregex, "\n");
```

I want the output to be like

```
1.skdhhfsdl
2. hkjkj
3.234hbn,m
```

But, i am currently getting

```
1.skdhhfsdl
 hkjkj
234hbn,m
```

Comment: Your `$1` will insert the captured group. If you don't want to include the space in the replacement, remove the `$1`?

Comment: Remove the regex delimiters, it is Java. Also, if there is 1 or more spaces, use `\s+`. We only capture what we need to keep. When you use `(\s)` and `$1` you *keep* the whitespace. Please provide some more details on what exactly your scenario looks like. Do you have control over the regex pattern? Well, try `parentString.replaceAll("\\s+(?=[0-9])", "")` if you need to remove those spaces before any digit.

Comment: thank u for your time, now i have updated the question.

Comment: Try `parentString.replaceAll("\\s+(?=[0-9])", "\n").trim()`

Comment: Java is not JavaScript, here regex isn't in form `/regex/flags` but simply `regex` (you can add flags with `(?..)` notation). Also your question and example doesn't match, since you are using match from group 1 (which is space) as part of replacement, so it will be replacing only matched number (and one additional character matched by dot `.` - since you didn't escape it).

Comment: check where the parenthesis are....and add an `$1` where you want the numbers to be

Comment: Aside from posting expected text please include in question *original* text which you want to change.

Comment: You must have `String parentString = "1.skdhhfsdl 2. hkjkj 3.234hbn,m";`, with no space at the start.

Comment: @Wiktor its not working

Comment: `...replaceAll("\\s(\\d)", "\n$1")`, or, more exactly what you want, that is, just replace the space: `...replaceAll("\\s(?=\\d)", "\n")`

Comment: @Samim [It does](https://regex101.com/r/Taf7Hb/1). You have not explained your scenario. [Maurice's solution also works](https://regex101.com/r/Taf7Hb/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew its not wokring. its woking in regex101.com but not in java 1.8.0_181

Comment: @Samim That means the regex works but you make some other mistake.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry its woking. tried too many suggestions and got my code messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the regex

```
\s+([1-9]+\.)
```

Notice that I captured the number part instead. When you are replacing, you usually capture the part you want to keep. Also note that I removed the leading and trailing slashes as those are not needed in Java. The `.` should also be escaped, like I did here.

The replacement is `\n$1`, meaning "new line, then group 1".

```
String parentString = " 1.skdhhfsdl 2. hkjkj 3.234hbn,m";
String myregex = "\\s+([1-9]+\\.)";
String output = parentString.replaceAll(myregex, "\n$1");
System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
String myregex = "\\s([1-9]+\\.)";
String output = parentString.replaceAll(myregex, "\n$1");
```

Comment: @Samim yes it is

Comment: sorry its woking. tried too many suggestions and got my code messy

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the expected output, you can use this regex.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String parentString = " 1.skdhhfsdl 2. hkjkj 3.234hbn,m";
    String myregex = "\\s+(?=[1-9]+\\.)";
    String output = parentString.trim().replaceAll(myregex, "\n");
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

This only matches one or more space that are followed by a number and dot and only replaces the space (because of lookahead) with a new line. parentString.trim() ensures that you don't get a newline before your first line.

Output:

```
1.skdhhfsdl
2. hkjkj
3.234hbn,m
```

Comment: It's working for me. Ok putting everything in main method so u can run as it is.

Comment: Well, I am getting the output I included in my answer. What is not working and what output you are getting?